# open, display and close serial port in Python

Tags: python-3.x, text, tkinter, pyserial

I want to make a gui which can open serial port, display received values in text widget and close it. Opening serial port is done but I can't find a way to display received values in text widget. Moreover the gui does not respond when I click open button. That is because of while loop used for displaying serial port data. I think that there must be serial port data receive event but I am clueless about it. How can I make display serial port data in text box and make other buttons respond after port is opened.

```
from tkinter import *
import serial

root = None

class serial_window(Frame):
    ser = serial.Serial()
    #open = 0

    def serial_open(self):
        if (serial_window.ser.isOpen() == 0):
            serial_window.ser.baudrate = 9600
            serial_window.ser.port = 4-1
            serial_window.ser.open()

                self.after_idle(self.writeline)  #while True:
                print(serial_window.ser.readline())

    def serial_close(self):
        if (serial_window.ser.isOpen() == 1):
            serial_window.ser.close()

    def open(self):
        self.OPEN = Button(self, text = "OPEN", fg = "blue", command = self.serial_open)
        #self.OPEN["command"] = self.open_port
        self.OPEN.grid(row = 0, column = 0)

    def close(self):
        self.CLOSE = Button(self, text = "CLOSE", fg = "blue", command = self.serial_close)
        #self.OPEN["command"] = self.open_port
        self.CLOSE.grid(row = 0, column = 1)

    def exit_main(self):
        self.exit_main = Button(self, text = "EXIT", fg = "red", command = self.quit)
        self.exit_main.grid(row = 0, column = 2)

    def console(self):
        self.console = Text(self, fg = "red")
        self.console.grid(row = 1, column = 0, columnspan = 3)

    def writeline(self, event):
            self.console.insert('insert', serial_window.ser.readline())
            if serial_window.ser.isOpen():
                self.after_idle(self.writeline)

    def createWidgets(self):
        self.open()
        self.close()
        self.exit_main()
        self.console()

    def __init__(self, master = None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.pack()
        self.createWidgets()


root = Tk()
app = serial_window(master = root)
app.mainloop()
root.destroy()
```

The data receiving continuously from serial port is - 'Monitoring \r\n'

Comment: Very difficult to replicate your problem since it depends on reading from actual serial port. Could you modifies it that it does not depend on it, and instead it read data, e.g. a file or or a pre-defined list.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest making `ser` an instance rather than class variable.  It will make the code more compact and even bit faster.  but answering as the code is...

You could write to your Text widget with a repeated callback method such as

```
def writeline(self, event):
    self.console.insert('insert', serial_window.ser.readline())
    if serial_window.ser.isOpen():
        self.after_idle(self.writeline)  # or self.after(1, self.writeline)
```

Replace the current `while True:` in serial_open with  a copy of the last line in the callback, to start the callback loop.  The `readline` call will still block which waiting for a complete line, but other events will be processed after the callback returns.

I have no idea how big a character buffer is used by the serial module, or how it handshakes with the character source.  It is possible that characters will be lost if other event delay the next call to writeline too long.

Comment: I edited the program as shown above. But the problem it seems persists. The program doesn't respond after I press 'Open' button and doesn't display serial data.